# how to remove error in function (android)

Tags: android

I am making an Android application that uses a button move to the next activity, but error arise

```
CAUSED BY: java.lang.nosuchmethodexception :std
```

This is my XML code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:onClick="std"
        android:text="Student Detail" />
```

this is JAVA code:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    public void std(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Student.class);
                startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Post full logcat please

Comment: post full code including the button onClick also, please.

Comment: Where is the `onClickListener` ?

Comment: @LancePreston not needed. S/he declared the onClick attribute in the xml.

Comment: are you sure button is in `activity_home` layout xml?

Comment: @Isabel the onClick is called `std()`

Comment: @DerGolem  no, there is no setOnClickListener

Comment: @IsabelHM When you declare the click handler method in the **xml layout**, there's **no need** for that in Java. I often use this syntax, which is very flexible, since **you can assign the same method to different Views** (it's easy to react differently to the different Views, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Change your button layout to this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:onClick="stdDetail"
    android:text="Student Detail" />
```

and also change your method to

```
public void stdDetail(View view) {
if(view.getId() == R.id.Btn ){
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Student.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
 }      
}
```

Comment: What improvement would this be? You are only changing the name of the method to be called ...?

Comment: No, it's also changing `getApplicationContext()` to `this`. But this doesn't solve the different layout file issue

Comment: Changing `getApplicationContext()` to `this` is probably a good idea. However I'm surprised this led to an upvote.

Comment: We can't JAVA's predefined  words like std as var or method name. Also you can add stdDetail to other button's onClick too. so you can handle more onClick actions using a simple method in multiple activities. @DerGolem

Comment: And who told you that `std` is a reserved keyword?

Comment: As I remember. Maybe I'm worng

Comment: @Marcus I'm surprised too.